# DLL linking - unable to find entry point

Tags: c++

I have DLL (openAL32.dll) and my program is using OpenGL. I am using Visual Studio 2010. In debug mode, everything works fine.
When I swich to release mode, I got this error when I try to run program (basicly, its translation from my Windows national language):

> Unable to fing entry point for eglCreateContext in dynamicly loaded
>   library OpenAL32.dll

There is no eglCreateContext in OpenAL32.dll and never was. Its not supposed even to be there.

I cant see any problem in my code (compilation and linking is OK) or in settings in VS. Program just crash in startup.

**EDIT:** Runtime library in VS at C/C++ Property pages is set to Multi-threaded (/MT) and Multi-threaded debug (/MTd) respectively. With /MTd in debug mode, it works fine

Comment: There are many reasons why this can happen, so knowing how you're linking to the DLL (e.g. sample command line) would help. My best guess is that the DLL is exporting the functions using indices instead of names, but you're linking using names, so things don't work at runtime. You can open the DLL using something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see how the symbols in the DLL are exported, and how your binary is linking to them.

Comment: are you running an older version of the DLL? Do you have the right declaration/import/export?

Comment: with your edit - does your library call such a function? does it expect it to be imported from openAL32.dll? Did you use the export/import macro trick and forget to define the preprocessor symbol in release mode?

Comment: The problem is, there is and never was no eglCreateContext in OpenAL32.dll.... its not supposed to be there either.  I only have lib, header and dll. eglCreateContext is not in lib or header from this

Comment: do you link any other DLLs that expects such a dependency? do you ever call that function yourself?

Comment: `eglCreatContext` is an openGL call; openAL is an audio library, I think.  So, clearly something is confused.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I know that, thats what I dont understand. Why it is looking for OpenGL functions in audio library. I am linking more libraries (ogg, pthreads, opengl) as DLL and zlib as static.